# Can one Fragment instance traverse between two Activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have been analysing the lifecycle of Activities and Fragments in Android and came up with a question - is it possible for one Fragment instance to be automatically put into a new Activity, after being created and shown?

Is there, for example, a configuration change scenario which would cause the Activity to recreate, but would then simply "migrate" the Fragments from the old Activity to the new?

The reason for the question is the idea of passing the Activity as a listener to its Fragments. I wonder if there is a situation (aside from the onSaveInstanceState serialisation) where this listener would be lost.

**EDIT:**

To make my idea clear - the reuse of a Fragment instance is an unwanted behavior. I want to make sure it will NOT happen by default.

Comment: To make my idea clear - the reuse of a Fragment instance is an unwanted behavior. I want to make sure it will NOT happen by default.

Comment: Then no.  Fragments will always stay within the scope of the Activity unless you or some other developer does something weird to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't anything in the official Android API that would allow that.  There is the `Fragment#setRetainState` method which allow `Fragments` to outlive their parent `Activity` during a rotation change, but it'll get reattached to the Activity that created it.  Fragments are basically controlled by the `FragmentManager` which is part of the Activity.  If the `Activity` goes away, then so does its `FragmentManager`.

Now, you could keep references of Fragments outside of the Activity's lifecycle. For example, keep a static reference of a Fragment somewhere in the Application or in the Fragment class itself, but this is going to cause so many headaches.  It goes beyond their use-cases and it's best to not even think about.

I think the only real solution is to keep Fragment states in a Bundle that contains various parameters that the Fragment understands.  You can pass this bundle around from Activity to Activity and the Fragments can rebuild themselves based on the Bundle state.  This also sounds like a hassle, but it can be done.